# How to change all strings in vector to uppercase?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a sequence of words from `cin` and store the values in a `vector`. After I’ve read all the words, I want to process the vector and change each word to uppercase.

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    vector<string> words;
    while( getline(cin, line) ) {
        words.push_back(line);
    }
    for (auto &c : words) {
        c = toupper(c);
        cout << c << endl;
    }
}
```

I am getting error at the `c = toupper(c)`:

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: Cygwin GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Ajay\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp||In function â€˜int main()â€™:|
C:\Users\Ajay\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp|15|error: no matching function for call to â€˜toupper(std::basic_string<char>&)â€™|
C:\Users\Ajay\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp|15|note: candidates are:|
\usr\include\ctype.h|20|note: int toupper(int)|
\usr\include\ctype.h|20|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from â€˜std::basic_string<char>â€™ to â€˜intâ€™|
\usr\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.8.2\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h|2596|note: template<class _CharT> _CharT std::toupper(_CharT, const std::locale&)|
\usr\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.8.2\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h|2596|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\Users\Ajay\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp|15|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Would be faster to find the bug if you were actually posting the error. That said, I will be right back with the solution.

Comment: `toupper` works on *characters* not *strings*.

Comment: This nice example why the C++11 `auto` keyword is not always a nice feature.

Comment: I think `&c : words` reads as **for every character in words**.

Comment: @ajkumar25 the container `words` is a vector of `std::string`, so `c` references to elements of vector i.e. `std::string` not _char_

Comment: @Dave `for (auto & c: str) c = toupper(c);` is also present in your link.

Comment: @ajkumar25 that's kind of hetepeperfan's point; auto in your code is referring to a string, but in that example it is a char. Don't use auto except for extreme circumstances.

Comment: @P0W Thanks man, you made it clear :)

Comment: Obligatory: you cannot convert a word to uppercase without knowing what language it is written in.

Comment: This question is asking how to change every string in a vector. The duplicate shows how to change just a single string. I'm reopening this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for(auto &word : words){
        for (auto &c : word) {
            c = ::toupper(c);
            cout << c << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably need a reference for `word` too

Comment: This code has undefined behavior if `char` is signed in the implementation and any of the characters in the string has the top bit set.